# Making pygame sprites disappear in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a rpg game and I want my playbutton to disappear as soon as it was pressed. Is there a method of which I can do that?
I have different game states they are: GAME, MENU, START
The playbutton will appear on the START game state and I want it to disappear when it is pressed or when the game state changes.
Thank you for your contribution

Comment: In tkinter, I would put start.unxyz() in the start click handler, where xyz is whichever of place, pack, or grid used to make it appear.  pygame must have a similar disappear method for sprites.  Search the docs again.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy There aren't anything equivalent in pygame. Once something is drawn to the screen it'll be there for the rest of the program unless drawn over with something else.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman The tk geometry methods put a widget in a widget list and the un- methods remove it from the list.  This seems equivalent to the pygame group.add and sprite.kill methods.  However, physical screen redrawing *is* different, and here you are right.  Tk works with the OS window manager, and user code is not directly involved.  'Draw over' happens automatically.  Pygame requires explicit screen drawing from the user: more flexibility, more responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

To remove something from the screen you need to draw something else over it. So the most basic answer would be to just stop rendering the button and start render other stuff over it.

A great way to go about it is making all your visible objects inherit [pygame.sprite.Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and put them in [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). From here you could draw, update and remove sprites easily.

Here's a working example. Press the keys 1, 2 or 3 to make the "Buttons" reappear again:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, size=(32, 32), image=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        if image is None:
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, size)
            self.image = pygame.Surface(size)
        else:
            self.image = image
            self.rect = image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.pressed = False

    def update(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
        if self.rect.collidepoint(*mouse_pos) and mouse_clicked:
            print("BUTTON PRESSED!")
            self.kill()  # Will remove itself from all pygame groups.

image = pygame.Surface((100, 40))
image.fill((255, 0, 0))
buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
buttons.add(
    Button(pos=(50, 25), image=image),
    Button(pos=(50, 75), image=image),
    Button(pos=(50, 125), image=image)
)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                buttons.add(Button(pos=(50, 25), image=image))
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                buttons.add(Button(pos=(50, 75), image=image))
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                buttons.add(Button(pos=(50, 125), image=image))

    buttons.update()  # Calls the update method on every sprite in the group.

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    buttons.draw(screen)  # Draws all sprites to the given Surface.
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is truly a sprite, you can:

- Add the sprite to a group called Buttons.
- Render the Buttons on the screen.
- Use the kill() method to remove the sprite from the Buttons group.
- Re-render the screen on the next round.

http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill